# SQLite - Autoincrement starting from a given value in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

In python I create a table in SQLite with:

```
"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ID(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT NOT NULL)"""
```

but since I'm creating different databases with same structure that I'm planning to join later, to avoid the pk conflict I want to give a starting value for the increment, like 10000. I've tried to put AUTOINCREMENT=10000 but I got:

```
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ID(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT = 10000, NAME TEXT NOT NULL)""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error
>>>
```

I've tried to use SQLITE_SEQUENCE but I got this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: SQLITE_SEQUENCE
>>>
```

Comment: I was looking for a different solution

Comment: Those solutions are all that exist.